# Call VBScript With Return Value on Remote Machine With Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, vbscript

I need to call a remote VB script from Powershell, and the VB script needs to run on the remote machine.

I have been using \$computer\root\cimv2:Win32_Process").Create(C:\test.vbs)

This works, however I can't get a return value from the script, just a return value from the win32 process.

I would convert the whole thing to powershell, but can't as I'm connecting to a legacy domain I can't install additional tools on so have to call the remote vbscript

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I would like to share my solution. It's the same as the one posted by Ansgar but it's been tested and working fine:

```
$VNC = '\\share\software\AppName\_Install_Silent.vbs'
$Computer = 'RemoteHost'
$TMP = "\\$Computer\c$\TEMP"

if (!(Test-Path $TMP)) {
    New-Item -Path $TMP -ItemType Directory
}

Copy-Item -LiteralPath (Split-Path $VNC -Parent) -Destination $TMP -Container -Recurse -Force -Verbose
$LocalPath = Join-Path 'C:\TEMP' (Join-Path (Split-Path $VNC -Parent | Split-Path -Leaf) (Split-Path $VNC -Leaf))
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {cscript.exe $Using:LocalPath} -Computer $Computer

# Restart might be needed of remote host
```

The difference is that you have to copy the files first to the remote machine to avoid the double hop issue and then you can install it with the `$Using` variable.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably try either remote invocation:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { cscript.exe "C:\test.vbs" } -Computer $computer
```

or [`PsExec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553):

```
PsExec \\$computer cscript.exe "C:\test.vbs"
```

Can't test either of them right now, though.